# Placement of a function gives unknown problems

Tags: php

I have this function that creates an array of a directories output.

```
public function getDirContents( $path )
{
     $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS );

    // Flatten the recursive iterator, folders come before their files
    $it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

    // Maximum depth is 1 level deeper than the base folder
    $it->setMaxDepth(1);

    $results = array();
    // Basic loop displaying different messages based on file or folder
    foreach ($it as $contents)
    {
        $fileInfo = array();
        if ( $contents->isFile() )
        {
            $fileInfo['dir'] = $it->getSubPath();
            $fileInfo['file'] = $contents->getFilename();
            $results[] = $fileInfo;
        }
    }


    return $results;
}
```

I have this in a class that I created and it works as expected.  I have an older script that I haven't rewritten to use this class.  so I placed this function (minus the public) in another file that contains random common functions and include the file into my old script.  However, when I call it I get the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FilesystemIterator' not found in /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/common.php on line 745
```

If I remove the FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS it works fine except I guess it loses that functionality.  I'm curious why this is happening.

Other things that may or may not explain what could be occuring.

The class that I use it in successfully is part of the main site.
The script where it errs is actually a subdomain.
I'm using php 5.3 (single file)
    -- This is bluehost's config for picking a version of php and this is how mine is set up. 
    PHP 5.3 (Single php.ini) Same as PHP 5.3, but all subdirectories will use ~/public_html/php.ini

This is why I was under the impression that my subdirectory (subdomain) would use that file.

The httaccess in the subdomain vs the main are not the same.

I'm not sure if those tidbits help but I'm at lose and I'm fairly new at this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And by placement of function you mean a differently configured subirectory, which might or might not use the required PHP 5.3 that  FilesystemIterator was introduced with?

Comment: I'll be honest that might be it.  I'm using bluehost and set it to be php 5.3 (single php.ini) so I assumed it was available in all places but maybe that's what I need to look into.

Comment: I guess the problem is namespaces. Either put `use FilesystemIterator;` between  your `namespace` declaration and `class ...` or tell php to look in the global namespace by using `\FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS`.

Comment: @complexenigma How can you set a PHP version in an php.ini? this isn't possible?!

Comment: By the way, can you use any of the SPL iterators on your subdomain?

Comment: I don't know if I can use any others.  This was some script I found and modified based on someone's post on here so I'm fairly green using  the iterator classes.  I'm not quite sure if I understand but I could just a back slash and it should work?